# Rails Find_by_id raises exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, exception, activerecord, impressions

I was led to believe that the difference between Object.find and Object.find_by_id is that find will raise a **RecordNotFound** exception whereas find_by_id simply returns nil if nothing is found.

However, in my Rails 3 app if I attempt to search my Uploads model with a bogus id I get:

> **ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UploadsController#show**
>
> Couldn't find Upload with id=59
>
> **Request**
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> {"id"=>"59"}

Here is the line of code thats messing up:

```
@upload = Upload.find_by_id(params[:id])
```

I'm using Rails 3.1.3.

Comment: That's odd. I tried in the console and worked. But i am using rails v 3.2.

Comment: It works in my console as well, just not in the application itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a problem with the [Impressionist gem](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist) that I'm using as it was hooked into my Upload show action and tried to execute it's own find before I had a chance to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

To throw the 404 error, it needs to be

```
Upload.find_by_id!(params[:id])
```

The exclamation point is the magic.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the original question, so I can't upvote, but it did answer my own question that led me here - "How do I get `find_by_id` to raise?". Thanks

Comment: @Nick haha. What was the original question?  Just looked back at it and I don't really see one...

Comment: I think he's trying to ask why he was getting an exception with `find_by_id` since it should not raise.