# find_by_id still triggers ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When querying for an non-existing post in my controller via

```
@post = Post.find_by_id(params[:id])
```

I get ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound. But when I do the same in the rails console I get nil returned.

I also tried `find_by_id!` (note the exclamation point) that is supposed to trigger a 404, but it still just gives me ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound.

I found out that a gem could cause this kind of problem (see question: [Rails Find_by_id raises exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148785/rails-find-by-id-raises-exception)), so my question is how do I figure out which gem that I use could cause the same problem?

This is my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.7'
gem 'pg'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'fancybox-rails', :git => 'https://github.com/sverigemeny/fancybox-rails'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'validates_email_format_of', :git => 'git://github.com/alexdunae/validates_email_format_of.git'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'thin'
gem 'chronic'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'twitter'
gem 'kaminari'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'compass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

group :development do
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'faker'
end
```

I don't see how I can just disable one by one until I find the Gem that might causes this problem because I will most likely trigger many other errors due to Gem dependencies in the process.

Anyone have any idea of how I should go about this?

**Update**
Here is the full stacktrace:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PostsController#edit

Couldn't find Post with id=123202

activerecord (3.2.7) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:341:in `find_one'
activerecord (3.2.7) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:312:in `find_with_ids'
activerecord (3.2.7) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:107:in `find'
activerecord (3.2.7) lib/active_record/querying.rb:5:in `find'
cancan (1.6.8) lib/cancan/model_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:20:in `find'
cancan (1.6.8) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:114:in `find_resource'
cancan (1.6.8) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:68:in `load_resource_instance'
cancan (1.6.8) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:32:in `load_resource'
cancan (1.6.8) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:25:in `load_and_authorize_resource'
cancan (1.6.8) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:10:in `block in add_before_filter'
activesupport (3.2.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418:in `_run__4208450199150212965__process_action__1027836660135587880__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.7) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.7) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.7) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.7) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.7) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.7) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.7) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.7) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
omniauth (1.1.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:177:in `call!'
omniauth (1.1.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:157:in `call'
omniauth (1.1.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:177:in `call!'
omniauth (1.1.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:157:in `call'
omniauth (1.1.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:177:in `call!'
omniauth (1.1.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:157:in `call'
omniauth (1.1.1) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.3) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
rack (1.4.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.7) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:473:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__503554315877740465__call__403817388267166975__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
quiet_assets (1.0.1) lib/quiet_assets.rb:20:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
actionpack (3.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.3) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.7) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
railties (3.2.7) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.7) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
rack (1.4.3) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.7) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:81:in `block in pre_process'
thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `catch'
thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `pre_process'
thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:54:in `process'
thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
eventmachine (1.0.0) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
eventmachine (1.0.0) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
rack (1.4.3) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in `run'
rack (1.4.3) lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `start'
railties (3.2.7) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
railties (3.2.7) lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
railties (3.2.7) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
railties (3.2.7) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
script/rails:6:in `require'
script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Can you post a stacktrace? Are you sure it's the line `@post = Post.find_by_id(params[:id])` that's causing this error? `find_by_id` without an exclamation mark shouldn't be raising an exception, only `find_by_id!` should be doing that...

Comment: I added the full stacktrace in the question.

Comment: Make sure params[:id] is actually not nil or an empty string

Comment: So it looks like this is being caused by cancan:

    `cancan (1.6.8) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:25:in 'load_and_authorize_resource'
    cancan (1.6.8) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:10:in 'block in add_before_filter'`

Can you add what you're doing with cancan in the controller? Or what you're doing with cancan to protect Posts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As drewinglis pointed out, this is caused by cancan.

Cancan loads the post to determine whether the user has authorisation to perform whatever action on it. If the post is not found, it will respond with a 404, ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound.

Here, Ryan goes into the reasoning behind this a little: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/43 he also suggests rescuing from the 404 if that's not the behaviour you require.

Answer (score 0):

drwesinglis and cheeseweasel are correct, this was caused by CanCan. I was not able to get the solutions from the post https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/43 to work, so I removed `load_and_authorize_resource` from my controllers and I am now checking manually if the user is authorized to complete the action.

My controller now looks like this:

```
@post = Post.find_by_id(params[:id])
if @post
  if can? :update, @post
    ...
  else
    flash[:error] = 'You are not authorized to access this post.'
    redirect_to root_url
  end
else
  flash[:error] = 'This post doesn\'t exist.'
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

I will update my code later in the development cycle to redirect to a nicer 404 page, but for now I just show the messages.